# What kind of expression do i use in a decide module to make an entity leave (false) if the resource set is completely seized?

Tags: arena-simulation

i'm trying to model a parking lot in Arena. i created a resource set named parking spots that the entities seize until all 20 of them are seized (if the decide condition is true), if false then the entities will leave the parking lot. i don't know the expression to do this.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a [mcve]. (it's a link- click it!).

Answer (score 0):

nvm just discovered the expression builder and used the following expression:

`NQ(Park Car.Queue) == 0`